# How do you say "cupcake"?

Tags: translation, word-requests, pinyin, simplified-characters

What is the pinyin and simplified Chinese characters used for the word cupcake?

When looking it up there is no reliable answer. Some people seem to just call it by the chinese words for "cake" but others use the chinese words for "small cake," "cup cake," or "cake in a cup."

So I just wanted to ask for the word that actual Chinese people use most/recognize.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's my honor to offer the first answer of the community for you ：）

I think you mean to 纸杯蛋糕  zhǐ bēi dàn gāo

Check out the imgs from baidu pics http://image.baidu.com/search/index?tn=baiduimage&ps=1&ct=201326592&lm=-1&cl=2&nc=1&ie=utf-8&word=%E7%BA%B8%E6%9D%AF%E8%9B%8B%E7%B3%95

Is it？If so, I guess right :)

Comment: Supplements: Formally we say纸杯蛋糕, but in reality people usually say蛋糕 for abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

Cupcake in Chinese should be [杯形蛋糕](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%E6%9D%AF%E5%BD%A2%E8%9B%8B%E7%B3%95&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-hLjjzbTTAhVh2oMKHdLpAxkQsAQIJA&biw=1416&bih=674) Bēi xíng dàngāo

Since most of the 杯形蛋糕 is served in a paper cup,  it is also commonly called as [纸杯蛋糕](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%E7%BA%B8%E6%9D%AF%E8%9B%8B%E7%B3%95&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi87KjjzrTTAhVD9YMKHc88Aq4Q_AUICCgB&biw=1416&bih=674)

Answer (score 0):

I'm Chinese. We just call it cake(蛋糕). Sometimes if others don't know what kind of cake is refering to, we'll add 'cake in a cup'“纸杯装的蛋糕”. Just like that.